# Installing Genymotion Eclipse plug-in

Tags: java, android, eclipse, genymotion

I have installed [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/#) on my Windows 7 , 32-bit machine. I am working with Eclipse to develop Android apps. I would like to ask what the proper way to install the Genymotion plug-in is.

Going by their [website](https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/launchpad/download/), they provide two JAR files for Eclipse and a note underneath which reads:

> The installation of the plugin can be done by launching Eclipse and
>   going to "Help / Install New Software" menu, then just add a new
>   Update Site with the following URL:
>   http://plugins.genymotion.com/eclipse. Follow the steps indicated by
>   Eclipse.  Warning: to use this plugin, Genymotion must be installed on
>   your system.

I have installed the plug-in from the Eclipse 'Help' menu. I havent downloaded any of the two files. Have I done it correctly ?

The two files are:
1. Genymotion Plug-in for Eclipse
2. Mandatory dependency for Eclipse plug-in

Comment: when you added the url as an "update site" and installed the plugins that where found there, than yes! Short question though, why don't you have tried to use the plugin?!

Comment: @WarrenFaith Doing that as I type this. Downloading the virtual device :)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

## Tutorials

This tutorial shows how you should do everything: 
http://www.slideshare.net/scentsome/eclipse-genymotion

And this is the original website tutorial:
https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/doc/

Both explain it perfectly

---

## Extra:

### Android Studio:

1. Go to File/Settings on Windows and Linux or Android Studio/Preferences on Mac OS X.
2. Select Plugins and click Browse Repositories.
3. Right-click (double-click for Mac OS X) on Genymotion.
4. Click Download and install.
5. Click Yes.
6. Click Close.
7. Click OK.
8. Restart Android Studio by clicking Restart.

If you want to do the manual method or want to see the instructions from their website, this is the link: https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/user-guide#genymotion-plugin-for-android-studio

### Eclipse:

If you want to have the genymotion virtual devices inside eclipse do this:

Go to help -> install new software -> add this link: https://dl.genymotion.com/eclipse

Answer (score 26):

For those who face `There are no categorized items` on Eclipse [image]

Uncheck `Group items by category`

Comment: That was the answer! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks a lot :) +1

Comment: Thanks you men !! +1

Answer (score 8):

[Follow this link](https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/doc/#collapse8), There you can see how to install genymotion eclips plugin.

`Eclips`>`Help`>`Install new software`>`Add`>

Type anything on `Name` box.

Inside `Location` box : `http://plugins.genymotion.com/eclipse`

Then follow the steps.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a demonstration to show how to install Genymotion in Eclipse ADT

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3sBHQqZ5TKk

Note: sometimes after additions of the plugin from *Help | Install new software* it is not giving the checkbox to check or the ability to install. At this time uncheck *"Group Items by category"* to list all items without any grouping. Check all of items then press *Next* and proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah dude you done it perfectly after installing genymotion you will see an icon in your eclipse when you click it then a window with genymotion devices will be shown

**(You must install genymotion virtual box and should have virtual devices in genymotion to run your app sucessfully)**