# Android emulator is not launched

Tags: android, eclipse

I've worked with the emulator fine from past 20 days. Suddenly, I got a problem with the emulator as it is not launching the app. It is not showing any error but taking much time and "Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched..." is shown on the console of eclipse.

emulator always showing like this: 
[image]

corresponding AVD configuration:

[image]

I am beginner in android development. Please help me to launch this AVD.

Comment: I wish we get simulator like the one for ios, it is mush smoother and fast. -_-

Comment: In emulation options check the snapshot. on first launch it will take time but after that it will be little fast

Comment: Try USE HOST CPU... I current create AVD as your configuration.. It works perfectly.

Comment: One more thing is : you use 8GB SD card and 2 GB internal storage, so minimum space required for tour storage is 10 GB, and RAM also must be 1GB free for your Emulator..

Comment: can you please tell me what is tour storage? and should I change any property in above configuration? @TechnoCracker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just removed and recreated the emulator and now it is working fine. Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Android emulator are notorious for their launch speed. I have just started to use Genymotion for development, trust me, it is much faster. (10 seconds boot up)

Here is the link of how to install it. 
[Installing Genymotion Eclipse plug-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109871/installing-genymotion-eclipse-plug-in)

Answer (score 0):

I've launched the emulator by creating that AVD again with the same configurations.

Anyway Thank you so much for your responses. By that I've learned some new things in android.

Thank you so much to all