# Cannot start a virtual Android device by genymotion from Eclipse

Tags: android, genymotion

I can start a virtual Android device using Genymotion and I have created 2 virtual devices. I installed the Genymotion Plugin in Eclipse (Luna), but when click the "Genymotion virtual Device manager " icon, there are no devices to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed [plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109871/installing-genymotion-eclipse-plug-in)  correctly, then its might be due to adb connection failure try to kill the adb.exe from taskManager[Windows] and restart your avd