# how to add genymotion plugin to eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, genymotion

I followed ways on the genymotion site but I got errors and I couldn't find other way. Please hepl me, how can I do that?

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

Comment: Install `Android Studio`.... If you don't want, read that answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/21109911/3626214

Comment: go to eclipse folder and find out plugin folder into it. paste genymotion jar in it.

Comment: thank you so much, I'll move to Android Studio maybe next few days, but now I have to develop on eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

You should uncheck the option group items by category.

[image]