# Installing Genymotion Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, android, eclipse, genymotion

This is a re-post of an answered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109871/installing-genymotion-eclipse-plug-in) because the answer doesn't work anymore. I cannot port my project to android studio at the moment due to a 3rd party dependency that i don't know when it will get updated.

The files i am looking for are:

1. Genymotion Plug-in for Eclipse
2. Mandatory dependency for Eclipse plug-in

If anyone can help me out, i would very much appreciate it! Cheers.

Comment: did you not go look on the genymotion website? https://www.genymotion.com/

Comment: Of course i went to look -.- I only found information related to Android Studio. Nothing shows up when i look for the plugin.

Comment: you obviously did not look hard enough https://docs.genymotion.com/Content/04_Tools/Genymotion_Plugin_for_Eclipse/Genymotion_Plugin_for_Eclipse.htm

Comment: Great, that says the same thing as the link i provided above, try it and see for yourself.

Comment: what about ti does not work

Comment: "There are no categorized items"

Comment: Is your third party dependency not in a JAR file? You can include that into Android Studio just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get 'There are no categorized items' when trying to install something with 'Install New Software' deselect the 'Group items by category' checkbox near the bottom of the install dialog to see the uncategorized items.